# React: rendering an Array of Data

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, axios

Working on my first react project and not making any progress on how to loop through and render my data to the front-end.

I am using axios to get a list of stock tickers from a MySQL database, and for each of those i am once again using axios to scrape some values from an external website.

See code snippet below:

```
const fetchStocks = () => {
    let stocksList = []

    Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/fetchStocks').then((response) => {
        response.data.map((val, key) => {

            const url = 'https://www.tradegate.de/orderbuch.php?isin=' + val.stockTicker
            Axios.get(url).then((response) => {

                let $ = cheerio.load(response.data)
                let name = $('#col1_content h2')[0].children[0].data
                let last = $('#last')[0].children[0].data
                let delta = $('#delta')[0].children[0].data
                let high = $('#high')[0].children[0].data
                let low = $('#low')[0].children[0].data

                stocksList.push({
                    sId: val.sId,
                    stockName: name,
                    stockTicker: val.stockTicker,
                    stockLast: last,
                    stockDelta: delta,
                    stockHigh: high,
                    stockLow: low
                })
            })
        })
    })
}
```

When i do  `console.log(stocksList)` i pretty much get what i want:

```
[
{
        "sId": 3,
        "stockName": "Tesla Inc.",
        "stockTicker": "US88160R1014",
        "stockLast": "1 049,80",
        "stockDelta": "+8,90%",
        "stockHigh": "1 049,80",
        "stockLow": "966,90"
    },
    {
        "sId": 1,
        "stockName": "Apple Inc.",
        "stockTicker": "US0378331005",
        "stockLast": "128,00",
        "stockDelta": "-1,16%",
        "stockHigh": "130,28",
        "stockLow": "127,70"
    },
    {
        "sId": 2,
        "stockName": "Intel Corp.",
        "stockTicker": "US4581401001",
        "stockLast": "42,725",
        "stockDelta": "+0,78%",
        "stockHigh": "42,85",
        "stockLow": "42,37"
    }
]
```

[image: Screenshot of chrome console output]

I would now like to do something like:

```
{
    stocksList.map(stock => {
        return ( 
            <li key = {stock.sId}>{stock.stockName}</li>
        )
    })
}
```

for each entry in the database, but so far i had no luck and don't quite understand where i'm wrong - im guessing something about how i'm setting up the array?

Comment: What do you mean by "no luck"? What is happening and how does that compare to what you expect to happen?  Also, where is `person` defined?

Comment: My fault, edited.

Comment: I've been following some tutorials for working with arrays and my no luck i am refering to neither the output i was hoping for nor any errors logged in the console.

Comment: I think you need to use useEffect hook to get the data and state variables to display the data.

Answer (score 0):

Since your are returning JSX you may want to use () braces instead of {}.

```
{
    stocksList.map(stock => (
        return ( 
            <li key = {stock.sId}>{stock.stockName}</li>
        )
    ))
}
```

Or simply:

```
{
    stocksList.map(stock => <li key = {stock.sId}>{stock.stockName}</li>)
}
```

P.S. also I don't see a part of your code where you are trying to render an array

Answer (score 0):

When the component did mount, **useEffect** will be called then it calls **fetchStocks** function, finally fetch data from the server and puts at a component state via **useState**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const FC = () => {
  const [stocksList, setStocksList] = useState([])

  const fetchStocks = () => {
      let list = []

      Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/fetchStocks').then((response) => {
          response.data.map((val, key) => {

              const url = 'https://www.tradegate.de/orderbuch.php?isin=' + val.stockTicker
              Axios.get(url).then((response) => {

                  let $ = cheerio.load(response.data)
                  let name = $('#col1_content h2')[0].children[0].data
                  let last = $('#last')[0].children[0].data
                  let delta = $('#delta')[0].children[0].data
                  let high = $('#high')[0].children[0].data
                  let low = $('#low')[0].children[0].data

                  list.push({
                      sId: val.sId,
                      stockName: name,
                      stockTicker: val.stockTicker,
                      stockLast: last,
                      stockDelta: delta,
                      stockHigh: high,
                      stockLow: low
                  })
              })
          })
      })

      setStocksList(list)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchStocks()
  }, [])


  return stocksList.map(stock => <li key = {stock.sId}>{stock.stockName}</li>)
}
```